# Rails rendering partials - Keep getting undefined method nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, partial

I'm new to programming and I'm working my way through rails. I'm trying to build small application but I'm quite stumbled by this problem. I've been adapting the Michael Hartl tutorial to build the app but I guess I'm missing something.

Below I have broken down the relevant parts of the code (hopefully) and I was hoping for some help on working out what the problem is.

The error is:

## undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

It might be useful to point out that I was getting a similar error before when trying to display a register-form partial on the home page. This was fixed with:

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/new', :locals => { :user => @user ||= User.new } %>
```

Doing the same thing on this occasion does remove the errors but the app acts as if I were signed in but does not let me sign-out or interact with any of the functionality.

I've tried various variations of the above including :@current_user => current_user, etc

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong as it seems that I'm not doing something right!

Thanks.

## USERS CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user,  only: [:show]
  before_filter :correct_user,    only: [:show]
  before_filter :admin_user,      only: [:index, :destroy]     

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])

  end

  def show
    @user = User.includes(:video_posts).find(params[:id])
    @video_posts = @user.video_posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render :template => 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end
```

## VIDEOPOST CONTROLLER

```
class VideoPostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :signed_in_user

  def create

  end

  def destroy

  end


end
```

## SESSIONS CONTROLLER

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

## SESSIONS HELPER

```
module SessionsHelper
 def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
end
```

## STATICPAGES > ROOT TO HOME

```
<%= render :partial => 'shared/user_info', :locals => { :current_user => current_user } %>
```

## PARTIAL IN A /SHARED FOLDER

```
<h2><%= current_user.username %></h2>
<span><%= link_to "view profile", current_user %></span>
<span><%= pluralize(current_user.video_posts.count, "video_post") %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

your partial wants to display data only a user with an account has. However when a user enters your homepage, there is no current_user object, because he is not jet signed in. you could enclose your render :partial call with something like this:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= render :partial ... %>
<% else %>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
<% end %>
```

Which displays the users information, only if he is signed in.

Comment: forwarding your answer I believe that technically means that when he is in the index action of the `UserController` he must be wanting to have something like this: `@user = current_user` which means that when the `index` action is rendered it will get the current_user. His problem is that [:username] is nil and he trying to retrieve value of id key from a nil object.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're saying. My interpretation of his question was, that he gets the exception on the first line of his partial, because current_user is nil, because he has no remember_token in his cookies. I'm not certain that is the right interpretation, but neither can I see that UsersController#index is involved.

Comment: Daniel you are right. Thank you so much! This does shed some light on things but the question still remains. How should I be rendering partials?

Comment: In your example you use a local variable current_user, so you invoke it perfectly right:
render :partial => 'whatever', :locals => { :current_user => 'your value' }

Comment: I see. I guess there's a million reason why the partial render might break. Something's still not right. Trying to do 

  <%= render :partial => 'shared/video_post_form', :@video_posts => video_posts %>  

to render

<%= form_for(@video_posts) do |f| %> etc

gives me, a no method error. Would be amazing if you could explain why? Thank you! :)

Comment: Oops okay it works with 

<%= render :partial => 'shared/video_post_form', :@video_posts => @video_posts %>     
    

and using :video_posts within the rendered partial. Still confuses me a lot. Thank you both for your help anyway!

Comment: I guess  <%= render :partial => 'shared/video_post_form', :video_posts => @video_posts %>  

is how it should be? that works too.. :)